# etoolbox package explanation requested

Tags: macros, etoolbox

I am trying to understand the following package `etoolbox`.
I am unsure about the meaning of the following syntax since I am not sure what is the correct question to ask in google or in the book of Knuth what to search.

```
\edef\etb@catcodes{\etb@catcodes}
```

I do not understand the meaning of the statement especially the `@` character. If anybody could explain it I would be thankful.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Since `etoolbox` treats basically with `LaTeX` you won't be successfully looking into D.E. Knuth's TeXBook. The `@` is a very often used technique in `LaTeX` to concat command sequence names etc and to hide the more elementary macros from ordinary user's application, since usage of `@`  requires some additional 'setup' -- it can't be used accidentally in this case, at least not without warning or error message. But your question itself is unclear

Comment: If you're specifically interested in the use of `@`, see [What do `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` do?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/5764) (possible duplicate).

Comment: This line is part of a few more lines of code which are important in order to understand the meaning of the particular definition. (basicically it is about saving and later restoring category codes of a few characters…)

Answer (score 5):

This part of `etoolbox` is rather tricky, but not really complicated, once one gets the idea.

When LaTeX executes `\usepackage`, the named file is loaded and `@` is considered as a letter, which makes it possible to use it in macro names.

The `etoolbox` package needs to change category codes in certain parts of it, so it wants to be sure to restore those settings at the end.

Here is the code:

```
\def\etb@catcodes{\do\&\do\|\do\:\do\-\do\=\do\<\do\>}
\def\do#1{\catcode\number`#1=\the\catcode`#1\relax}
\edef\etb@catcodes{\etb@catcodes}
\let\do\noexpand
\AtEndOfPackage{\etb@catcodes\undef\etb@catcodes}
```

The first instruction stores a list of the characters that potentially change their category code in the package, to be restored at the end.
The `\do` macro is a traditional macro for defining lists, and it can be redefine to *execute* the list. In this case it is redefined so that, for instance, `\do\&` expands to

```
\catcode\number`\&=\the\catcode`\&\relax
```

If the code after the definition of `\do` was just `\etb@catcodes`, TeX would transform the above code into

```
\catcode 38=4
```

which would be useless, because this *is* the current setting. Instead, `etoolbox` wants to save these settings for the end, so it does

```
\edef\etb@catcodes{\etb@catcodes}
```

which does similar complete expansions for all stored characters. Since `\edef` does complete expansion before assigning the meaning to `\etb@catcodes`, there's no danger of infinite loop; at the end, the definition of `\etb@catcodes` is equivalent to

```
\def\etb@catcodes{%
  \catcode 38=4\relax
  \catcode 124=12\relax
  \catcode 58=12\relax
  \catcode 45=12\relax
  \catcode 61=12\relax
  \catcode 60=12\relax
  \catcode 62=12\relax
}
```

but with a fundamental difference: if some package has changed the category code of, say, `|` to 13, there would be

```
  \catcode 124=13\relax
```

in the definition of `\etb@catcodes`.

At the end of the package, `\etb@catcodes` is executed, so restoring all category codes to the previous state and the macro is undefined.